Need to get the result in array(row(tid array(varchar), res varchar)) format using Trino SQL
I have a table - NS_Data



ns
tid
res
nid




PQR
ITKT20254
not include
A


PQR
ITKT20223
not include
A


PQR
ABCD23456
not include
B


PQR
ABCD54321
not include
B


PQR
ITKT21111
include
A



I want the output in following format



ns
nid
finalMap




PQR
A
[{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223],res=not include}, {tid=[ITKT21111],res=include}]


PQR
B
[{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}]



I want the type of finalMap
array(row(tid array(varchar), res varchar)). I got the result with json but is is not compatible with the expected array(row(tid array(varchar), res varchar)) format. I tried this query-
WITH dataset(ns, tid, nid) AS ( values ('PQR',  'ITKT20254',  'A'), ('PQR', 'ITKT20223',      'A'), ('PQR', 'ABCD23456',     'B'), ('PQR', 'ABCD54321',    'B'), ('PQR', 'ITKT21111',     'A') ) select ns,nid, cast(row(tradelist , res1) as row(tid array(varchar), res varchar)) as finslMap from (select ns,nid,tradelist,res1 from (select ns,nid, array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist, 'not include' as  res1 from dataset group by ns, nid union select ns,nid, array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist, 'include' as  res1 from dataset group by ns, nid))

If order of the columns in the resulting row type is not important than you can use multimap_agg and follow it with map_entries with some casting:
-- sample data
WITH dataset(ns, tid, res, nid) AS
(
    values ('PQR',  'ITKT20254',    'not include',  'A'),
    ('PQR', 'ITKT20223',    'not include',  'A'),
    ('PQR', 'ABCD23456',    'not include',  'B'),
    ('PQR', 'ABCD54321',    'not include',  'B'),
    ('PQR', 'ITKT21111',    'include',  'A')
)

-- query
select ns, nid, 
    cast(map_entries(multimap_agg(res, tid)) as array(row(res varchar, tid array(varchar)))) 
       as finalMap
from dataset
group by ns, nid;

Output:



ns
nid
finalMap




PQR
A
[{res=not include, tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223]}, {res=include, tid=[ITKT21111]}]


PQR
B
[{res=not include, tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321]}]



If order is fixed then you will need to add extra step to reorder columns in the row.

can you please re-arrange the columns

I have executed same query . I'm getting result as- {{res=not include, tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321]}}. Expected the last {} as []. IS this because of trino?

@Prachi this is output of the query in Trino.

@Prachi as for the rearrangement of columns - it is easy - just create a new row with needed order.

they why im getting end brackets as {} instead of []

PQR B   {{res=not include, tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321]}}
PQR A  {{res=not include, tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223]},{res=include, tid=[ITKT21111]}} ..I'm getting this result with above query. Nedd [] as end brackets

@Prachi maybe it is just a display issue. Where and how do you evaluate the query abd check the results?

I'm using DbVisualizer Free 13.0.3 , PrestoDriver, trino-jdbc-357.jar

I tried the one more query to get this format. Getting the finalMap as

{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include}
{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=include}
{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}
{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=include}

I want the result format-

[{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include},{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=include}]
[{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include},{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=include}]

@Prachi I use Trino console to execute the query and it gives the "expected" format. Check out type of the resulted column by using typeof - if it is array(...) then the problem is in the visualizer. If it is not - you are executing some other query =)

Can you please modify the new query for expected result.
